# WPF animation: enlarge-stay-shrink

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If it is only enlarge and shrink, it is easy.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.BeginAnimation(Button.FontSizeProperty, new DoubleAnimation( 40,
                           new System.Windows.Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)),
                               FillBehavior.Stop) { AutoReverse = true });
}
```

But now I hope when the font size grows to 40, stay for 2 seconds, then shrink. How to do this?

Comment: Take a look into [DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingkeyframes.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine several animations into a [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx), that should do the trick.
You can combine the following animations:

- One that enlarges the font size up to 40
- One that does nothing (with a duration of 2 sec)
- One that shrinks the font back